# Is there any way to insert an excel that contains UDF in a MS Word without an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an user-defined function in excel. It works well. However I have to insert that Excel file in MS Word as an object, and when open that file from MS Word, my UDF turns to #NAME.

I already keep my UDF as an add-in to make it available in all the workbooks.

I want it works when it is attached in MS Word too. Is there any way to fix it that not copy and paste as value. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The issue is probably that if it is in the Excel add-in the add-in is only loaded in Excel but not in Word (therfore Word doesn't find the UDF because it is not loaded. Try to put the UDF code into the Excel file itself (not the add-in) and try again.

Comment: I have tried to save the function in personal macro workbook. It wouldn't work with function. Is there any way to make it both in other workbooks and workbook object.

Comment: I didn't mean to save if in the personal workbook. I mean to save the UDF in the workbook that you are inserting into Word.

Comment: So i have to save the UFD in every file I work with?

Comment: @PassornR. How else is it going to be referenced?

Comment: @PassornR. yes. Give it a try.

Comment: Did it fix your problem? If so, could you make it a proper answer @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @PassornR. Made it an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that if it is in the Excel add-in the add-in is only loaded in Excel but not in Word (therfore Word doesn't find the UDF because it is not loaded).

Put the UDF code into the Excel file itself (not the add-in) so it is available if Word loads that Excel file.